# Python's synthetic way to select negative components of a vector

Tags: python

if I have for example a vector like

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,-3,4,-5])
```

if I want to create a vector `b` with the negative values of `a` I can of course do a `for` loop

```
list=[]
for i in a:
    if i<0:
        list.append(i)
b=np.array(list)
```

but I am sure that there is a better way. What is a more synthetic, python-ish way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are inherently able to be selected by a boolean array, so:

```
a=np.array([1,2,-3,4,-5])
b=a[a<0]
```

Gives

```
>>> b
array([-3, -5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
b = np.array([i for i in a if i < 0])
```